# (PuTTY:27843): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:15:42.205: cannot open display:

Tags: putty, xquartz

I am using a mac os machine and when I installed Putty I got this error. I have installed all the required software to install Putty but it didn't work.

I have installed :-

- MacPorts
- Homebrew
- Command Line Tools for Xcode
- Xcode (accepted the license agreement)

I resolved this issue using another application that needs to be installed.

The main problem is with X11.

I installed [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/)

After installation open it and go to Application on top.

Click on Terminal and type putty. (command + N) - shortcut for opening terminal

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been banging my head since hours due to this issue. Opening the terminal FROM XQuartz -> Application and typing "putty" there helped. I was trying to open putty from the regular terminal till now!